# cron can not find the command pyenv

Tags: linux, cron, pyenv

I set up the cron to access to the python environment.

pyenv shell ammt-crawler  is work find in  command line

this is my init.sh file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export PATH="${HOME}/.pyenv/scripts:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

pyenv shell ammt-crawler
```

but log saying that it can not find the pyenv command

```
./scripts/init.sh: line 4: pyenv: command not found
./scripts/init.sh: line 5: pyenv: command not found
./scripts/init.sh: line 7: pyenv: command not found
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Struggled with the same issue on macos.
Eventually bypassed pyenv and activated the python virtual environment directly in the shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
source /Users/ptrk/.pyenv/versions/<virtualEnvName>/bin/activate
python ...
```

if you are using the command directly in your crontab know that it is default `shell` and not `bash`. Therefor `source` won't work, use the following syntax instead:

```
*/10 * * * * . /Users/ptrk/.pyenv/versions/<virtualEnvName>/bin/activate && python ...
```

Answer (score 1):

if in ubuntu 18.04, export PATH=~/.pyenv/shims:~/.pyenv/bin:"$PATH" should be added to ~/.profile

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 adding the shims and bin path worked. I was able to run a shell script from crontab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. By adding `export PATH=~/.pyenv/shims:~/.pyenv/bin:"$PATH"` to my bash script, pyenv was able to successfully be found.

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Deploying-with-pyenv

Comment: Please provide the code for the solution - try not to just provide a link, but rather provide actual code snippets and comments that explain how your solution addresses the problem.